# Networking issue post Ubuntu22 upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade

I am new to Ubuntu22, I upgraded from 20 to 22 version. Most things are working, except the  browsing part.

My machine starts as normal. I can see the WiFi is connected to my home network. But I cant use web, in any browser, I get an issue - connection refused. In CLI also, "apt update" or "curl" fails as it can't connect to network. Most weird thing is, I can still connect to VirtualBox, start my Kali and use internet normal in Kali. But it doesn't work in Ubuntu. What can be done?

I know a long solution. Restart the machine, login to advanced menu, go to recovery mode, enable networking, then "apt update && apt upgrade" in root shell. And then start the machine. Somehow it works. Wonder what is causing the problem and how can I solve without going into recovery mode always. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04? Because those are *not* the same as Ubuntu Core 20 and Core 22, which go by year only. Regular desktop versions of Ubuntu go by year.month .

Comment: `apt` is not a 20 or 22 command; as 20 & 22 are *snap* only Ubuntu products, the `apt` being a *deb* package command found in 20.04 & 22.04 systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes made it start working

Change /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf to add:

```
[main]

rc-manager=resolvconf
```

and then:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```